# SQL query fails but the transaction rollback doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

The actual column names are account and passwd so the second query will failed, but the first query still inserted into database.

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO users (account, passwd) VALUES ('account+1', 'password+1')";
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO users (account, password) VALUES ('account+2', 'password+2')";
try {

 $db->beginTransaction();
 $db->query($sql1);
 $db->query($sql2);
 $db->commit();

} catch (Exception $e) {
  $db->rollback();
  die($e->getMessage());
}
```

The transaction started successfully with no errors, the problem is that it doesn't rollback, always rows are inserted regardless of failing queries.
MySQL version 5.5.25 and table type is InnoDB.

Comment: This is PDO? Do you have it configured to throw exceptions?

Comment: Any reason you're hard-coding values into your queries? You should be using SQL placeholders for that.

Comment: @tadman I assume this to be just a test scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you turn on exceptions? By default pdo doesn't throw them and silently ignores errors.

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it's working now!
So that's means i have to even set the error mode to PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION in my production project in order to use transaction?

Comment: no. that has nothing to do with transactions. the problem was that you were using exceptions, but pdo wasn't throwing any. so the catch block code would never execute. in non-exception mode, pdo returns boolean false when errors occor. if you'd done `$db->query(...) or die(...)` you'd have seen the script abort on that first query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO user (account, passwd) VALUES ('account+1', 'password+1')";
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO users (account, password) VALUES ('account+2', 'password+2')";
try {

 $db->beginTransaction();
 $db->query($sql1);
 $db->query($sql2);
 $db->commit();

} catch (Exception $e) {
  $db->rollback();
  die($e->getMessage());
}
```

`$mysql` refence is wrong, you have to use, `$db->rollback();`

Comment: oh yeah, sorry it actually is $mysql in my codes, i've just changed to $db for this question

Comment: so look at the Marc B answer :)